# Python - Program not exiting loop correctly

Tags: python, while-loop, breakout

I'm just a beginner but I cannot figure out why my code is not exiting the loop correctly.

```
import uuid

class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self, name, id, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance + amount

    def can_withdraw(self, amount):
        if  (amount <= self.balance):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount

    def printAll(self,outfile):
        print(self.name, "|", self.id, "|", self.balance, file = outfile)

    def balance(self):
        return self.balance

def main():
    menu = eval(input("Main Menu. Type 1 for new customer, 2 for existing, 0 
        to exit. "))

    while (menu != 0):
        if (menu == 1):
            name = input("Enter account holder: ")
            balance = eval(input("Enter beginning balance: "))
            id = uuid.uuid4()
            account = Bank_Account(name,id,balance)

            first,last = name.split()
            fileName = first + last
            outfile = open(fileName, "w" )
            account.printAll(outfile)

            print("********Account created********")
            print("Account number: ", id)
            print("Account name: ", name)
            print("New balance: ", balance)
            print("*****************************")
            outfile.close()
            menu = eval(input("Main Menu. Type 1 for new customer, 2 for 
                         existing, 0 to exit. "))

          elif (menu == 2):
            name = input("Enter account holder: ")

            first,last = name.split()
            fileName = first + last
            outfile = open(fileName, "r")

            lines = outfile.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                info = line.split("|")
            name = info[0]
            id = info[1]
            balance = int(info[2])
            account = Bank_Account(name,id,balance)

            print("Summary:\n", name, "Account Number: ", id, "Balance: ", 
                  balance)

            outfile.close()

            menu2 = eval(input("Type 1 to deposit, 2 to withdraw, 3 for 
                          balance, 0 to return to main menu: "))

            while (menu2 != 0):
                if (menu2 == 1):
                    outfile = open(fileName, "w")
                    amount = eval(input("How much would you like to deposit? 
                                          "))
                    account.deposit(amount)
                    account.printAll(outfile)
                    print("Account number: ", id)
                    print("Account name: ", name)
                    print("New balance: ", account.balance)
                    outfile.close()
                    menu2 = eval(input("Type 1 to deposit, 2 to withdraw, 3 
                             for balance, 0 to return to main menu: "))
                elif (menu2 == 2):
                    outfile = open(fileName, "w")
                    amount = eval(input("How much would you like to 
                                         withdraw? "))
                    withdrawal = account.can_withdraw(amount)
                    if (withdrawal == True):
                        account.withdraw(amount)
                        account.printAll(outfile)
                        print("Account number: ", id)
                        print("Account name: ", name)
                        print("New balance: ", account.balance)
                        menu2 = eval(input("Type 1 to deposit, 2 to 
                      withdraw, 3 for balance, 0 to return to main menu: "))
                    else:
                        print("Error, attempted to withdraw more than total 
                        balance, try again.")
                    outfile.close()
                elif (menu2 == 3):
                    print("Your account balance: ", account.balance)
                    menu2 = eval(input("Type 1 to deposit, 2 to withdraw, 3 
                              for balance, 0 to return to main menu: "))



    print("Have a nice day!")



main()
```

My problem is that on inputting 0 for menu2 it again goes to 
`elif (menu == 2) : name = input("Enter account holder: ")`. Instead it should prompt for input at the outer loop. Why is the code not breaking out of this inner loop?

Comment: It is breaking out of the inner loop. However, `menu` retains whatever value it had prior to entering the outer loop (in this case 2), so in your current setup it will repeat the initial code that got you to the inner loop in the first place. "Enter the account holder" is part of the outer loop, so ot should be clear that you broke out of the inner loop by seeing that text. Please change `eval(input(...))` to `int(input())`. `eval` should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask user again for his choice at the end of the while loop. The value of the variable `menu` is not changed for your case.

```
menu = eval(input("Main Menu. Type 1 for new customer, 2 for existing, 0 to exit. "))
while (menu != 0):
    if (menu == 1):
        .....
    elif (menu == 2):
        .....
    menu2 = eval(input("Type 1 to deposit, 2 to withdraw, 3 for balance, 0 to return to main menu: "))

    while (menu2 != 0):
        .....
    menu = eval(input("Main Menu. Type 1 for new customer, 2 for existing, 0 to exit. "))
```

Comment: Please get rid of `eval(input())` and cast to `int`. That code is terrible and dangerous practice.

Answer (score 0):

First input line :

```
menu = eval(input("Main Menu. Type 1 for new customer, 2 for existing, 0 
    to exit. "))
```

You can even use :

```
  menu = int(input("Main Menu. Type 1 for new customer, 2 for existing, 0 
    to exit. "))
```

This should be inside the while loop , if you expect it to break to the outer loop

Suggestion :  There should be more pythonic ways to acheive the same , when you are in Rome do like Romans

Comment: Please get rid of `eval(input())` and cast to `int`. That code is terrible and dangerous practice.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at end of main function:-

```
menu = int(input("Main Menu. Type 1 for new customer, 2 for 
                         existing, 0 to exit. "))
```

You are not moving to main menu after the menu2 is 0, That's why it is not breaking properly.

Comment: 3 answers to this question and not one corrected `eval(input())` :(. Please cast to `int` instead.

Comment: Actually he should cast testing digits to string, Coz these are string numerals meant to identify the situation not to be used for calculation, right?

Comment: OP could also do that but on a minor point I'd say that was less clear. Anything to get rid of `eval` though is preferable.

Comment: As you've left your answer currently, it will now only work with Python 2 and the problem of `eval` is still there.